# Best way to get all combinations from multiple lists in Python (keeping duplicates)

Tags: python

I have the following lists:

```
items1 = list(range(0,48))
items2 = list(range(0,61))
items3 = list(range(0,48))
```

I am trying to create all the possible combinations among the lists in groups of 3 elements, as follows:

```
combinations = [(items1[i],items2[j],items3[k]) for i in range(len(items1)) for j in range(i+1, len(items2)) for k in range(len(items3))]
```

This works nice, but what it gives me is a set of unique combinations. For example, if the first element is (0,0,1), I won't find the elements (0,1,0) or (1,0,0) in "combinations". What I would like to have is the following result:

```
(0,0,0)
(0,0,1)
(0,1,0)
(1,0,0)
...
(48,61,48)
```

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this result? Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for *permutations*? Checkout itertools

Comment: I checked it out and yes, that's it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will return what you're looking for:

```py
import itertools

itertools.product(items1, items2, items3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggesting itertools, I have found out that the solution is as easy as this one:

```
import itertools
a = [items1,items2,items3]
combinations = list(itertools.product(*a))
```